# Foursquare API, oauth, HTTP 301

Tags: oauth, node.js, foursquare

i'm playing with the foursquare api in nodejs.
I follow the steps described [here](http://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html) (Web server application)

but in the last step, when i'd get the authorization_code i get an HTTP 301 pointing to the same url which was requested.
I don't know why.

do i miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started implementing my own solution based on the new 4sq api (v2) and oauth2

<strike>https://github.com/yikulju/Foursquare-on-node</strike>

Comment: please update your link as it is offline now, dead link goes to a github 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [connect-auth](https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth)? It is a pretty good library and it also supports [foursquare](https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth/blob/master/examples/app.js#L75).

To install:

```
npm install oauth connect-auth
```

To use try:

var foursquareConsumerKey = "";
var foursquareConsumerSecret = "";

```
 app.get ('/auth/foursquare', function(req, res, params) {
    req.authenticate(['foursquare'], function(error, authenticated) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
      if( authenticated ) {
        res.end("<html><h1>Hello foursquare user:" + JSON.stringify( req.getAuthDetails().user ) + ".</h1></html>")
      }
      else {
        res.end("<html><h1>Foursquare authentication failed :( </h1></html>")
      }
    });
  })
```

I think your code must look something like this, but I have not tried it yet, because I don't have foursquare account.

Comment: thanks, the only problem with this version is that it uses the old 4sq api and oauth v1